# Angular 2 validate input based on mask

Tags: angular, validation, angular-forms

I'm using [this plugin](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/angular2#readme) within my Angular 2 project to mask some inputs.

The problem I have with this is to validate if the input has the proper mask applied.

Whenever I try to check for the value it's alwayas `valid`. For example, I have a mask to fill a phone number, just like in the example:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <input [textMask]="{mask: mask}" type="tel" formControlName="phone" />
  `
})

export class AppComponent {
  public myModel = ''
  public mask = ['(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, ')', ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]
}
```

But even when I fill, let's say, 2 numbers `(11_) ___-____` it's considering the field as `valid`.

I tried to se a custom Validator to check for the input length, but it's also passing, since it's being prefilled with `_`.

```
this.registerForm = this._fb.group({
    'phone': [null, Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(14),
        Validators.maxLength(14)
    ])],
});
```

I don't know how to create a validation for this type of scenario, envolving more complex validations.

Comment: you need to write a `custom validation` code to strip the masking characters and return `true` or `false`

Comment: The following should work as expected: `Validators.pattern(/^\([1-9]\d{2}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}$/);` [**Test**](https://regex101.com/r/9Snh4M/1).

Answer (score 1):

Just registering the correct answer from @developer033. It worked like a charm for me.

> The following should work as expected:
>   Validators.pattern(/^([1-9]\d{2})\s\d{3}-\d{4}$/);

Although I used a pattern that fit my needs.